# How to create nested dictionary without losing data?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the file which contains distance values for a set of nodes in matrix form. I extracted those values and want to save them in a nested dictionary.

I already tried, but my dictionary contains only values from the last iteration.

```
d={}
i, j = 0,0
for f in tmp:
    for k in range(3,len(f),3):

        d[nodes[i]] = {}
        d[nodes[i]][nodes[j]]= f[k-2]+f[k-1]        


        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0


return d

 d={'A': {'P': '5'},
    'B': {'P': '3'},
    'C': {'P': '6'},
    'D': {'P': '5'},
    'E': {'P': '3'},
    'F': {'P': '33'},
    'G': {'P': '21'},
    'H': {'P': '39'},
    'I': {'P': '4'}}
```

But d should contain:

```
d={"A":{"A":5,"B":6, "C":7, "D":8, "E":9, "F":10, "G":11;"H":12, "I":13},
   "B":{"A":3,"B":4, "C":5, "D":8, "E":9, "F":14, "G":11;"H":12, 
        "I":16}},.....
```

Comment: The snippet is incomplete. What is in `nodes` dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You're re-initializing the second-level dict each iteration of your inner loop. That is what is causing it to "lose data".

Instead, you could use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
i, j = 0,0
for f in tmp:
    for k in range(3,len(f),3):
        d[nodes[i]][nodes[j]]= f[k-2]+f[k-1]        
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0

return d
```